# How can I do faster search in Lucene index?

Tags: java, performance, lucene

My index size is near about 35 GB.
I have created indexes using FSDirectory.
But While searching it is too slow.

when I am trying to query against index its latency in first query is around 13 milisec.
I read more lucene docs but not helpful to me.

What should i do for decreasing latency?
any thoughts?

I'm using lucene version 3.5 .

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed

Comment: 13 milliseconds is too slow? Part of that will be disk seeking time which is unavoidable without changing hardware.

Comment: hey, I have read above docs .I follow all suggestion still no effects on latency.my h/w specification is 4GB RAM,64 bit os.please suggest me how I  decreases  latency that I get in second query.

Comment: What do you mean by "how I decreases latency that I get in second query"? If you mean how you get your first query to run as fast as the second query, you technically can't since at the time of your second query, your operating system has likely cached the lucene index's files accessed from the first query. To simulate this, you should warm up your searcher.

Comment: I've read about "How to warm lucene searcher" . would you please suggest me how I do warm a searcher .My index are stored in to disk. and I have also use one index searcher.